# Navigate to Report from LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to redirect to a Report in Report Builder from a LWC.
However I did not find any substantial information that specifically mentions redirection to "Report" page type , inside the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type).

This is what I tried:

In Markup :::

```
<div>
    <a href={reportUrl} onclick={redirectToReport}>View Report</a>
</div>
```

In JS controller :::

```
redirectToReport(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.reportUrl);
}

connectedCallback() {
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: '/lighting/r/Report/00OR0000000PCHYMA4/view'
        },
    }).then(url => {
        this.reportUrl = url;
    });
}
```

However I get back this message in console: Target page has no matching URL

I tried passing the hardcoded URL directly to the NavigationMixin but I get back the exact same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want to navigate to standard object record page ***Report***, you will not need **href** attribute. You can directly use ***Record Page*** navigation on click. Below is how you can implement:

HTML:

```
<a onclick={redirectToReport}>View Report</a>
```

JS:

```
redirectToReport(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: '00OR0000000PCHYMA4',
            objectApiName: 'Report',
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });
}
```

Just recheck and confirm that **00OR0000000PCHYMA4** is correct report id.