# Navigate to Report with dynamic filters from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have requirement in which need to navigate to report page with dynamic filters(`fv0`) in the URL from LWC.

Please let me know how to add report filters in the `attribute{}` ?

**Similar post:**
[Navigate to Report from LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282084/navigate-to-report-from-lwc/300973#300973)

```
redirectToReport(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: '00OR0000000PCHYMA4',
            objectApiName: 'Report',
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
redirectToReport(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropagation();
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: '00OR0000000PCHYMA4',
        objectApiName: 'Report',
        actionName: 'view'
    },
    state:{
         fv0:dynamicFilterValue
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Code dumps (where you provide code but no explanation) typically don't make very good answers. The explanation is as important as the solution because the explanation helps build the comprehension required to avoid similar problems in the future. You can add an explanation (what is the issue? how does this solve it? what is the important part?) by making an [edit].